# Adressing columns of a variable dataframe in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm having trouble combining writing in a certain column of a certain dataset in a for loop. Basically I have identically structered datasets w2,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8 and I want to perform the same operation on the same column of each dataset. For example, I want to recode the gender variable from 1 = male, 2 = female to 0 = male,1 = female and then factor it. Here is how I do it for w2.

```
w2$gender <- case_when(w2$gender == 1 ~ 0, w2$gender == 2 ~ 1)
w2$gender <- factor(w2$gender,
                    levels = c(0,1),
                    labels = c("Male","Female"))
```

I want to build a for loop that does it for all my dataframes, but I'm constantly running into issues as I can't seem to adress the column of the changing dataset.

```
for(i in w){
  z <- paste0("w",i)
  eval(call( "<-",eval(as.name(z))[,4], case_when(eval(as.name(z))[,4] == 1 ~ 0, eval(as.name(z))[,4] == 2 ~ 1)))
}
```

I get the error:

> Error in c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
> :    invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

I tried sevral different approaches like using assign function etc. but nothing seems to work. Do you know of an easy way how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to use a loop, get the values of the objects (`w1`, `w2`, ..) in a `list` with `mget`, loop over the `list` with `map` and `mutate` the `gender` to change the values from 1, 2 to 'Male', 'Female' respectively (there is no need to first convert 1, 2 to 0, 1 and change it back as in `R`, indexing starts from 1)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^w\\d+$')) %>%
      map(~ .x %>%
                mutate(gender =  factor(c("Male", "Female")[gender], 
            levels = c("Male", "Female"))))
```

If we want to update the original objects, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have just two questions. If I use this, it says gender is a character, can I also factor it using this technique? And will this work the same way if I use it in a regression and its not coded 0 and 1?

Comment: @Phate Just wrap with `factor` (updated the post).  In `R`, indexing starts from 1.  So, if you have `factor`, the integer index will be starting from 1, i.e. `v1 <- factor(c('Male', 'Female', 'Male'), levels = c("Male", "Female"));as.integer(v1)
[1] 1 2 1`

Comment: @Phate I specified the `levels` as by default it does go by alphabetic order where `F` goes before `M`

Answer (score 1):

We could save your dataframes in a list `list_df` then apply the function `my_function` to all elements (dataframes) of the list:
@akrun: What do you think is this reasonable?

```
library(dplyr)
my_function <- function(x) {          # x is the dataframe you want to change
  x$gender <- case_when(x$gender == 1 ~ 0, 
                        x$gender == 2 ~ 1)
  x$gender <- factor(x$gender,
                     levels = c(0,1),
                     labels = c("Male", "Female"))
  return(x)
}

df1 <- structure(list(gender = c(1, 1, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(gender = c(2, 1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

list_df <- as.list(c(df1, df2))

library(purrr)
list_df %>% lmap(my_function)
```

Output:

```
$gender
[1] Male   Male   Female Female
Levels: Male Female

$gender
[1] Female Male   Male   Female
Levels: Male Female
```

Comment: `as.list(c(df1, df2))` does not do what you think: it's a single list with all columns from df1 and df2. The reason is, a dataframe is a list, and `c()` concatenates lists. Why not simply `list(df1, df2)`?

Comment: Thank you Jean-Claude Arbaut!! Interestingly I get another output with list(df1, df2)

Comment: How would you update the original data frames? if I use the same method as akrun used for his answer, it doesnt work.

Comment: @Phate You can use `get` and `assign` to work with objects in the global environment, by name. Don't do that with `eval`. `mget` and `list2env` should also work though, and it's better as you can deal directly with a list. What doesn't work?

Comment: I copied your code and after that I used: "list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)" to update the df1 and df2 data frames, but I got the error: "Error in list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name"

Comment: @Phate Ah, yes, of course. `list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)` (or changes names before storing in the environments), otherwise the list is unnamed, and obviously you can't store list entries in variables with no names.